# How would I change the tabbar separator line?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, user-interface, tabbar

There exists a black line which rests on top of all tabbars and you seemingly have three options, remove it, customize it, or keep it.

I already know how to remove it, and for those who are looking at this to find out how to do so the code in Swift is

(put in app delegate)

```
    let tabbar = UITabBar.appearance()
    tabbar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    tabbar.translucent = false
    tabbar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
```

But anyway, I'm curious about the second option, customizing it. I've seen some apps color it and make it a part of their overall theme. I'm curious as to how one can achieve this.

Comment: Try subclassing `UITabBar`.

Comment: @HarvantS. Hm. That may work, I was hoping for something I could do in the delegate.

Answer (score -1):

> The separator is a UIImageView that is a 
>   subview of the tab bar. You can find it in the tab bar's hierarchy and set it to hidden.